# How do I change my map location in my Battlelog leaderboards?

Tags: battlefield-4, battlelog

I have just set my location in the battlelog leaderboards map. I set my location when I was not zoomed into the city level - I set my location when it was zoomed at state level.  My problem is that I accidentally selected the wrong city!  This causes a problem when I want to see the skill level in my city or nearby cities.

*See below: This was the map level I selected my location at.*
[image: battlelog map]

*See below: This is the city location I am set at for when I click on the general tab to compare skills to people nearby.  **This city is incorrect.***

[image: battlelog navigation]

How can I change my default location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually JUST figured this out.  In the top right hand corner of the map, you can click the change gear to change the location.  This will bring you back to the original select location screen:

[image]

[image]